# final keyword when passing an instance of java.lang.Number to a method

Tags: java

I was thinking about is there any sense to use final keyword in a method signature when passing an instance of java.lang.Number (ex. java.lang.Long)?

I think that it does not make any sense because java pass object reverences by value. That means java passes a copy of the original reference to the method. Any changes in value on this Number is invisible outside of the method. So it does not matter if the method changes or not the value inside the method.

Of course when we pass a pojo to a method then it makes sense to use the final keyword but it is a different scenario.

**java.lang.Number demo**

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long longValue = 1L;
        System.out.println("Long before: " + longValue);
        System.out.println(trickyMethod(longValue));
        System.out.println("Long after: " + longValue);

        BigInteger bigIntegerValue = BigInteger.ONE;
        System.out.println("BigInteger before: "+ bigIntegerValue);
        System.out.println(trickyMethod(bigIntegerValue));
        System.out.println("BigInteger after: " + bigIntegerValue);
    }

    private static String trickyMethod(Long value) {
        value = 10L;
        System.out.println("  trickyMethod: " + value);

        if (value.equals(10L))
            return "  equal";
        else
            return "  different";
    }

    private static String trickyMethod(BigInteger value) {
        value = BigInteger.TEN;
        System.out.println("  trickyMethod: " + value);

        if (value.equals(BigInteger.TEN))
            return "  equal";
        else
            return "  different";
    }
}
```

**And the output**

```
Long before: 1
  trickyMethod: 10
  equal
Long after: 1

BigInteger before: 1
  trickyMethod: 10
  equal
BigInteger after: 1
```

**POJO demo**

```
public class Demo {

    static class Container {
        private Long l;

        public Container(Long l) {
            this.l = l;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(l);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            Container c = (Container) obj;
            return l.equals(c.l);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container container = new Container(1L);
        System.out.println("Container before: "+ container);
        System.out.println(trickyMethod(container));
        System.out.println("Container after: " + container);
    }

    private static String trickyMethod(final Container container) {
        container.l = 10L;
        System.out.println("  trickyMethod: " + container);

        if (container.equals(new Container(10L)))
            return "  equal";
        else
            return "  different";
    }
}
```

**And the output**

```
Container before: 1
  trickyMethod: 10
  equal
Container after: 10
```

Why developers use final keywords in method signature like this `String method(final Long value)` in case of `Long`?

Comment: reuse of variables and parameters (with changed semantic) is quite often source for weired and hard to find bugs. The `final` keyword gives you a compiler error if you try to give your parameter a new value. Also for internal reason the parameter must be `final` when it is used within an anonymous class created in that method.

Comment: in `trickyMethod ` you're reassigning `container.l` which is not final field. If you reassign `container` itself, there should be compiler error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter ever, whether the parameter is immutable or not. A final mutable parameter can be modified internally, you just can't reassign anything to the parameter variable.

One of the more useless things in Java, it would be nice if the parameters were implicitly final, as it's a code smell if you're reassigning a parameter. Most code analyzers report it as a bug/warning/etc.

The basic rule of thumb is, unless syntactically required to make the parameter `final` (in very rare cases), don't bother putting final in the parameters since it will just create useless clutter in the code. However never reassign parameters, as it can be bug-prone, and *pretend* that all parameters are final.

Answer (score 3):

the reason why developers use the following is simply to prevent the variable from being re-assigned.

e.g

```
void method(final long value){
  long number = 90;
  value = number; // COMPILER ERROR
}
```

So, I guess if you don't want to accidently reassign it later on when reassigning it will result in it bad situation then you can declare it as final.

Comment: Not in this case.

Comment: sorry, can you expand on that?

Comment: What you write is true ;) but the question itself is about pass by v. and pass by r.

Comment: oh okay i see :), well this was his question "Why developers use final keywords in method signature like this String method(final Long value) in case of Long?", I guess I just answered that. ;)

Comment: The OP is asking this question, but I think he has another problem.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw. Besides. in your example the method is returning `String`, but in the body it is not so. return value should be `void` and even if you remove `final` keyword, there would be compile error anyway, because 60 is an `int` type not `long`, you'd better write 60L;

Comment: @pyramidPeak I'll edit that part and yes I will also edit that. was just a quick demonstration, but thanks anyway. appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

All of the `java.lang` package wrapper classes are immutable.  That includes String, Long, Double etc.  Hence you are correct that it doesn't matter if we mark them final.  But remember that in your example you are reassigning `value` reference.  In case of say `StringBuilder`, that would be new object reference.

But you are right, doesn't matter in case of immutable objects.

Comment: *"All of the java.lang package wrapper classes are immutable."* whether we use `final` or not on method parameters has nothing to do with that.